# FireBaseUI recyclerView in a Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to load data from Firebase using FrebaseUI into a recycler view but I can't seem to make it work in an `Activity Fragment`. When I tried it in a *normal activity* it worked just fine, am using a `fragment` because I want my data to be part of a tabbed layout. I have searched many YouTube tutorials but many of them are not using the Firebase recycler view. Is there anything I'm missing from my `Fragment` class or is the entire layout of my code just wrong because I have tried quite a number of times?

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

public class MarketFeedFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    View v;
    ProgressDialog progress;
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_market_feed_fragment,container,false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        this.v = view;
        getPosts();
    }

    private void getPosts() {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("market");
        databaseReference.keepSynced(true);

        recyclerView  = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.feedRecycler);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post ,MarketFeed.PostViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Post, MarketFeed.PostViewHolder>(
            Post.class,
            R.layout.market_row,
            MarketFeed.PostViewHolder.class,
            databaseReference
        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(MarketFeed.PostViewHolder viewHolder, Post model, int position) {
                final String postKey = getRef(position).getKey();

                viewHolder.SetItemName(model.getItemName());
                viewHolder.SetItemDescription(model.getItemDescription());
                viewHolder.SetImage(getContext() ,model.getImage());
                viewHolder.Setemail(model.getItememail());
                viewHolder.SetLocation(model.getItemlocation());
                viewHolder.Setcategory(model.getItemcategory());
                viewHolder.Setcondition(model.getItemcondition());
                viewHolder.SetPrice(model.getItemprice());
                viewHolder.SetUserName(model.getUsername());
            }
        };

        firebaseRecyclerAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
                super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);
                int friendlyMessageCount = firebaseRecyclerAdapter.getItemCount();
                int lastVisiblePosition =
                        layoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                // If the recycler view is initially being loaded or the
                // user is at the bottom of the list, scroll to the bottom
                // of the list to show the newly added message.
                if (lastVisiblePosition == -1 ||
                    (positionStart >= (friendlyMessageCount - 1) &&
                    lastVisiblePosition == (positionStart - 1))) {
                    layoutManager.scrollToPosition(positionStart);
                }
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: (Welcome to SO!) (Why do you mark your question as a block quote? (The `> ` at the start of the lines before the next empty one)) Assuming this *is* what is [needed to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): what is the result, and what about it makes you state `[can't] seem to make it work`?

Comment: You will have to excuse me, am new to stack over flow rules, I just need to get data from firebase using firebase recycler in a fragment